# Rspec include_examples working but it_behaves_like not (with tags)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a set of shared examples like this:

```
shared_examples_for 'a shared behavior' do
    it 'should pass number 1', :tag1 do
        expect(1).to eq(1)
    end
    it 'should pass number 2', :tag1 do
        expect(2).to eq(2)
    end
end
```

In another file, I import this file and have:

```
describe 'my test' do
    include_examples 'a shared behavior'
end
```

and when I run

```
rspec --tag tag1
```

My tests from my shared example run fine.

However if I simply change my 'include_examples' to 'it_behaves_like', rspec ignores those tests completely.

My hunch is that it has something to do with the tagging, but I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but I think you need to put your it_behaves_like inside contexts.

Comment: Trying this did not change the behavior.